# Benefit from old downloaded files

Tags: steam, borderlands

I downloaded Borderlands and then, without making a steam backup file of it, I reset Windows, I found that all the files of the game was not removed and then I put in a folder with its code (8980) in the downloading folder in steam library and Steam says its checking found files but then trying to download the full game (10.7GB).

Is there is solution to this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "reset Windows" ? Do you mean you reinstalled Windows on the same HD, without wiping it first?

Comment: I used the Reset Windows option in Windows 10, It's also available in Windows 8 and 8.1, I removed all apps but, kept my files.

Comment: I have the game files but, can't make Steam read them and download the missing files only.

Comment: You put it in the wrong directory. You should have left it in directory it was originally installed in (eg. `C:\Program Files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\Borderlands`). The `steam\steamapps\downloading` folder is just a staging area for the download. Steam doesn't check for any existing files in the download directory, only in the install directory. Instead it will wipe the download directory and replace it with empty placeholder files that it will download the files into. The files you put in the download directory have had their contents wiped, so you'll probably need redownload it all.

Comment: @RossRidge Is there a reason you haven't posted that as an answer?

Comment: @Studoku Because it's not a solution, and it's a bit speculative to what's actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to steam settings, then to the downloads tab. Add the folder with the borderlands files as a library.

Otherwise, try to copy the borderlands folder to your steam library's common folder. The file hierarchy should look like this in the end`(SteamLibrary)\steamapps\common\borderlands`.

Comment: I think I placed it in the wrong place and Steam did remove alot of the folder content, seems like it will download it over again.